# Cannot use capital letters in word

Tags: malware

I just opened a word document in docx format and I am unable to type the letter T as a capital. I can type it in other word documents on the same computer.

The reason I am asking it on this site, is because I believe it may be malware.

Insight?

Comment: Does a full [malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/) scan return any hits? After resolving those hits, does your problem persist?

Comment: This question is off topic for this site as it is not a programming issue.

Comment: This site is for programming related questions, which is clearly explained in the [help]. The fact you think you might have issues with malware on your system does not magically make your question become programming related. Voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to download Combofix(can be install from http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/) and start by running it in *safe mode*.
Then you can do a full system scan. I recommend downloading Malwarbytes, Super Anti Spyware, and Spybot Search and Destroy. Start them, do the updates then do a full scan with all of them. If everything is fixed uninstall all of them since they are all trial(re install when needed).